# How to get user details from SQL Server session like user ip,host name etc

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to get user all possible details from SQL Server session like user ip, host name etc. I have searched about `sp_who`. Any expert can guide me how I can achieve this? I have searched a lot but not found master piece

Answer (score 6, accepted):

may be i exactly don't know what you are expecting

but this may help you

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE spid = @@SPID
```

in this we can find username,host etc..;

Comment: to get current session queries i have used this DECLARE sqltext VARBINARY(128)  SELECT sqltext = sql_handle  FROM sys.sysprocesses  WHERE spid = (SPID)  SELECT TEXT  FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sqltext)